Unable to print more then one column using bulk collect
I need to print all column data using bulk collect how do i need to achieve it
My emp table as : id , name , salary
This id, name , salary need to be printed as an ouput
Below is my PLSQLcode
declare 

  type v_nest is table of emp%rowtype;
  v_rd v_nest := v_nest();
  
begin

     select * bulk collect into v_rd from emp;
  
     for i in v_rd.first..v_rd.last
     loop
        dbms_output.put_line(v_rd(i));  // Why this does not work 
     end loop; 
     
end;


dbms_output expects a scalar - you can't pass it a record with multiple columns, which is what each element of the v_rd collection is (a record/object of type emp%rowtype). So, simply break it out any way you wish into your own string of choice, by adding the column names to your record references:
declare 

  type v_nest is table of emp%rowtype;
  v_rd v_nest := v_nest();
  
begin

     select * bulk collect into v_rd from emp;
  
     for i in v_rd.first..v_rd.last
     loop
        dbms_output.put_line(v_rd(i).id||','||v_id(i).name||','||v_rd(i).salary);  
     end loop; 
     
end;

A useful academic exercise, but of course all this is entirely unnecessary. You'd get the same results in a more usable format simply by a straight query without any PL/SQL at all:
select id,name,salary from emp;

